# How do you upload a single wheel file to a pypi server?

Tags: python, pypi, python-wheel

I have a wheel file for a compiled package from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-igraph). I would like to host this on my internal pypi server. Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! Just change to the directory where your wheel file is, then...

```
pip install twine
twine upload file_name.whl --repository-url https://pip.server_name.com/
```

You may be asked to enter you pypi username and password if required. The uploaded package name will be the same as the local filename.